# Is it possible to call firebase functions with 'firebase-admin' package?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I have node app with service account based access, so I used `firebase-admin`. As I could see before, `firebase-admin` mostly duplicated `firebase` package (except for authentication part, signatures and maybe some other parts), but now I want to invoke functions and I can't find any equivalent for `firebase.apps[0].functions().httpsCallable('myFunction')`. I looked into Typescript typings, and they don't even mention functions.

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert('./service-account-credentials.json'),
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
});

const config = {
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
};

const storageBucket = admin.storage().bucket(config.storageBucket);
const firestore = admin.firestore();



// const functions = admin.apps[0].functions(); // not possible
const functions = firebase.apps[0].functions(); // possible, but Firestore.apps not initialized
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `firebase-functions` **client** for calling Callable Cloud Functions in the Node.js Admin SDK for Firebase.

It is not an unreasonable request though, so I recommend filing a feature request on the [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node), so others can weigh in too.

In the meantime, the only option is to implement the [wire protocol for callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) yourself, possibly based on their [implementation on the regular JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/functions).

Comment: thanks for an answer, was expecting something like that. Was actually thinking about initializing another app for 'firebase' lib using email and password of firebase user.

Comment: I landed here looking for a way to use `httpsCallable` from my Google Cloud IoT device running Nodejs. I need to call a cloud function that makes a request to Mender to preauthorize the device on their platform. from a systemd service when the device first boots. @DougStevens mentions using a service account [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024495/using-httpscallable-with-service-credentials), which I have, but it doesn't sound like that fixes my situation. Any new developments with this or suggested work arounds?

Comment: The workaround mentioned in my answer is still the only one I know of.

Comment: I tried running with the web sdk as it notes it is here that it is suitable for "IoT devices running Node.js." [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase). But it throws;                `menderPreAuth Error: Error: internal
(node:773) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: internal
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (/data/node_modules/.pnpm/@firebase/functions@0.6.1_e9d66a23fa701e65014ff8d410061da5/node_modules/@firebase/functions/dist/index.node.cjs.js:62:28)` What is "Error: internal"?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a good place to help with that. If you have a problem implementing Cloud Functions in your app, post a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up with this code. User id is firebase user uid.

```
const firebaseApp = async (userId: string) => {
  if (firebase.apps?.length) {
    firebase.apps.forEach((app) => app.delete());
    console.log(`Deleted ${firebase.apps.length} apps`);
  }

  const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(userId);
  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

  await firebaseApp.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken);

  return firebaseApp;
};
```

```
const firebase = await firebaseApp('WObPvJbZDIR9WB72Tun8Jg4D0ky2');

await firebase
  .functions('europe-west1')
  .httpsCallable('myFunction')(doc);
```